# "Missing these required gems" on specific server, gems are installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Trying to run rake db:migrate I get:

```
$ rake db:migrate
(in /home/user/domains/staging)
log level debug
Missing these required gems:
  haml  ~> 3.1.4
  htmlentities  
  fastercsv  

You're running:
  ruby 1.8.7.72 at /usr/bin/ruby1.8
  rubygems 1.3.7 at /home/user/.gem/ruby/1.8, /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8

Run `rake gems:install` to install the missing gems.
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- json
```

I have two servers en both are updated via a git repository. On one server everything works fine, on the other I get the above error.

Whats up?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `bundle install` or `sudo bundle install` in production? You might also try `bundle exec rake db:migrate` instead of just `rake db:migrate`. These are kind of guesses, but might help.

Comment: Nope, I still running Rails 2.3. Somehow when I do this, it works: /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2011.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake db:migrate

Answer (score 0):

Is the path to the "ruby"/"rake" etc executables pointing at the correct one on the server that isn't working? It looks like you want to use REE, but your stack trace is 1.8, not REE.

You may need to export an environment variable to update your path to point at the correct Ruby binaries.